# To Parse Excel Sheet using Apache Poi in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, excel, apache

Is it possible to parse excel sheet using Apache Poi in javascript??

I need to parse an excel sheet using apache poi and need to get the response as json object. I have tried the code that enclosed with the below link.

http://blog.ipsolns.co.uk/2007/09/11/reading-excel-using-javascript-and-apache-poi/

I have got this error Uncaught ReferenceError: Packages is not defined

Please anyone can help me to parse the excel sheet using javascript

Answer (score 1):

Is it absolutely necessary to use POI library? 
The library below does a fairly awesome job in parsing excel using Javascript.

http://oss.sheetjs.com/js-xlsx/